# Restarting daemons on C++ program exit in RHEL 7 and 8

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system

I am writing a program in C++ that must run on both RHEL 7 and 8 and requires the use of ntp/chrony. By default, the RHEL 7 machines do not use chrony, but have it installed. As of RHEL 8, it appears that only chrony is used. In my situation, ntpd/chronyd are always running on the machines in question, with variable settings in each machines config file.

When my program executes, I wish to direct the machines to a specific NTP server rather than whatever is in the machine's config. On program exit, I wish to direct the machines back to whatever is in their config file. I do not wish for the user of my program to have to run a script "in addition" to my program, or in anyway have to manually deal with these settings (if the program itself executes a script or another program, that's fine, I just don't want the user to need to execute an additional script themselves). Edit for emphasis and clarity: I *cannot* have the user execute a program "in addition" to the original program, and the *must* be able to execute the original program itself without the use of a script or something similar. These are external requirements that are imposed upon me.

I wish to handle the largest number of plausible situations in which the program can exit, such as a successful program exit or exiting due to a kill command. I have very little systems programming experience and limited operating systems knowledge, so I'm wondering the most elegant way to handle this.

I'm currently think about handling this by writing a subprogram (via bash or another language) as a sort of "process monitor". At start, my original program will make the necessary system calls to stop ntpd/chronyd, call direct the machine to the new NTP server via chronyd (which is installed on both machines). Then, it will spawn this "process monitor" subprogram as a separate process. When the original program exits for whatever reason, my subprogram will restart ntpd/chronyd and exit.

Is this the best/only way to handle this situation, or is there a more elegant solution that would involve only executing my original program, and could restart these daemons at program exit?

Comment: Just make a script to run your app. Set whatever settings you want first, than execute the app, than reset settings back. Getting too smart here is not necessary.

Comment: And your idea of a "watchdog" requires a tricky double fork in order for the child not to just get killed when the parent dies, which is likely going to result in follow-up problems. Mostly as it will then restart chrony/ntpd asynchronously outside the expected service state change.

Comment: @SergeyA I appreciate the idea, but I have certain requirements that are not in my control and this is not an option in my situation.

Comment: @Ext3h thank you for mentioning this, I was not aware this would be an issue.